# Is it possible to have a 1 to 0 or 1 recursive relationship and how to query such table?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, entity-relationship, data-modeling

I have this Ticket table supposed to be used in a Queue system where I can forward a ticket from a Service queue to a different queue.

My Ticket table has fields such as `number`, `ticketRequest` (timestamp of when the ticket was created), `expectedCallTimestamp` (timestamp of predicted call to be attended), etc...

Here's the CREATE SCRIPT for the table Ticket:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `ticket` (
 `ticket_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `wrong_ticket_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `number` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `forwarded` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `answered` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ticketRequest` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `expectedCallTimestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `callTimestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `serviceDuration` time DEFAULT NULL,
 `service_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `organic_unit_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `device_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `counter_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ticket_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `UQ_ticket_wrongTicketId` (`wrong_ticket_id`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `FK_ticket_queue` (`service_id`,`organic_unit_id`),
 KEY `FK_ticket_device` (`device_id`),
 KEY `FK_ticket_workerbycounter` (`user_id`,`counter_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_ticket_device` FOREIGN KEY (`device_id`) REFERENCES `device` (`device_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_ticket_queue` FOREIGN KEY (`service_id`, `organic_unit_id`) REFERENCES `queue` (`service_id`, `organic_unit_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_ticket_workerbycounter` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`, `counter_id`) REFERENCES `workerbycounter` (`user_id`, `counter_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

OK, so what I thought was - when a client picks a different service that he intended to pick (it happens sometimes) I, as the operator behind the counter, can create a new ticket with the same `ticketRequest` timestamp of the *wrongServiceTicket* and use that *wrongServiceTicket's*.`ticket_id` to reference it through a *forwardedTicket's*.`wrong_ticket_id` (the one that has the intended/correct service) for several purposes.

My approach to this is having a **1 to 0 or 1 recursive relationship** on the table Ticket, with a nullable & unique field of `wrong_ticket_id` that is the same as the *wrongServiceTicket.*`ticket_id` when a *forwardedTicket* is created, as previously explained.

Here's a data model example of what I'm trying to build:
[image: Data Model]

Is it possible to have this implementation or is there a better way to handle this problem? And how do I select the info of the *wrongServiceTicket* when, for example, calling the next ticket in line when having a ticket that's forwarded in the same queue as other tickets that aren't?

Comment: What do you mean by "recursive relationship"? A **table-self-reference** (where a table has an FK that references the same table's PK) is not called "recursive" (when "recursive" is used in reference to tables, relations and SQL it's usually referring to hierarchical structures and queries using recursive-CTEs).

Comment: I'm having trouble spotting a concrete question in here.  Of course it's *semantically* possible; to some degree, you're doing it (though you need a foreign key to enforce it). What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Hadn't finished the question guys, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: The correct implementation is to keep the field `ticket_id` always populated with the current/last ID. IF you in addition want to keep a history about the changes of the values inside this field - you will need a separate history table for that. But keeping a history is an entirely separate activity than ensuring that `ticket_id` is always the right value for `the moment`.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you intend to establish parent-child relationship between existing ticket (wrong one) and new ticket (corrected one).

Your suggested approach is viable except few minor corrections -

1. Keep wrong_ticket_id column as NULLABLE as it can be null in most of the tickets which were created with a valid service.
2. You can optionally put a check constraint on wrong_ticket_id. This column will be populated only when 'forwarded' = True.